# creating basic Google Script to Copy SS and Save to a particular folder on my drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a basic script that I found works pretty good for my needs. The file I want to copy gets updated once a day.  The person that updates it just overwrites the file every day so I'm trying to store a historical copy of the file, into a folder on my drive.  The script below does copy the file and creates the file for me.  However I am trying to polish up a few things.

```
    function DailyPerformanceCopy() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger('DailyPerformanceTrigger')
  .forSpreadsheet('ENTERSPREADSHEETIDHERE')
  .onEdit()
  .create();
  var date = new Date();
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(date,'America/Chicago', 'MMMM dd, yyyy'));
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ENTERSPREADSHEETIDHERE");

   //Make a copy of the template file
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('ENTERSPREADSHEETIDHERE').makeCopy().getId();

  //Rename the copied file
  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('Performance ' + date);
}
```

1. I would like the copied file to only be saved as Performance + The current Month, Date, Year. (Performance March 16 2020.  Tomorrows copy to be saved as Performance March 17 2020, etc)

Its currently being saved as: Performance Mon Mar 16 2020 14:45:09 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

2. Its currently being saved to the root of my drive.  I'd like it to be saved to the folder I created called "Performance"
3. Im not sure if it will execute tomorrow after the file gets updated.  Im assuming so?

Comment: If you have been running that for very long then I would recommend that you go into your current project triggers and delete some of the onEdit() triggers and then only create a trigger if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: I have not been running this for any amount of time.  I am putting this together starting today.  I have not been running this at all.  I did run it from my editor shell ,and it does indeed copy and save a file to my drive.

Comment: Well, you should always check to see if you already have a trigger with that name before creating another.

Comment: Understood.  This was the first script I've ever created so I can't imagine I have other triggers

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I'm getting an error when this tries to run on change:

Your script, Daily Performance Copy, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

The script is used by the document Performance.

Start Function Error Message Trigger End
3/18/20 9:56 AM DailyPerformanceCopy Authorization is required to perform that action. change 3/18/20 9:56 AM

Comment: It sounds like you need to authorize the script.  You can probably do that by running any function in the project from the script editor.  It will determine which scopes are required and then give the user the opportunity to authorize it.

Comment: You can even run a null function like `function doesnothing(){\\doesnothing}`

Answer (score 1):

```
function DailyPerformanceCopy() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("**************ENTERSPREADSHEETIDHERE******************");
  const dfldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('************Enter Folder Id***************')
  if(notTrigger('DailyPerformanceTrigger')) {ScriptApp.newTrigger('DailyPerformanceTrigger').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();}
  const ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'America/Chicago', 'MMMM dd yyyy');
  const file=DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
  const name=Utilities.formatString('Performance %s', ts);
  file.makeCopy(name, dfldr);  
}

function notTrigger(funcname) {
  const tA=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for(var i=0;i<tA.length;i++) {if(tA[i].getHandlerFunction()=='funcname') {return true;}}
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I dont have edit access to the original file so I will see tomorrow after it updates.  Thank you again!